# jquery getting in to .click function twice when i click enter

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 3 fieldsets. If the user wants to go to the second fieldset he can do this or by clicking on the Next button or by pressing enter, only the enter part does not work well because it activates the enter button two times.

I have read other articles as well. But still when i focus and click on enter (for which i use this code:

```
    $("#msform").keypress(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault() 
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $(".next").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then it goes in to this function:

```
$(".next").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //current_fs current fieldset
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    var fv = formValidation(event);
    if (fv) {
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

but i keeps doing this:

```
  current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    var fv = formValidation(event);
    if (fv) {
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

2 times.

I know that

> Because hitting "Enter" when focus is on a button triggers the "click"
>   event natively. You also get a "keypress" event, and from that you
>   trigger the "click" event again.

But even preventdefault does not work in my situation.

***General HTML of the form which I am talking about:***  http://jsfiddle.net/xvxpha7p/  < Remember to focus on a field first.

Can someone help thanks

Comment: if pressing enter triggers click natively then why do you need a keypress event to trigger the click?

Comment: Can you add the html as well? So are you trying to make it so that enter anywhere on the form triggers the next event and then clicking next does the same? but if focus is on next you don't want it to just do it once?

Comment: try    $(".next").one('click', function(e) {
    //do your code here
});

Comment: @Dhunt i removed some parts of the form and only get the general html: https://jsfiddle.net/q2uaodbf/

Comment: can you paste the html as well

Comment: @srinath does not work unfortunately

Comment: var counter = 0;
 var counter = 0;  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    counter++;
    if ( counter > 1 ) {  //do your code here
    }
});

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to work as you have said it does.

Comment: The way to make this things in a form is to handle `onsubmit` event, because you don't have to make tricks with `onclick` and `onkeypress` events. One event to handle everything. Try onsubmit :)

Comment: @Dhunt i updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvxpha7p/ please focus on field first and then press enter

Comment: @marcos Perez Gude, my form has 3 fieldset and the final got a submit button which posts data to the server so unfortunately i cannot put everything in the onsubmit :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the click event, thus there's no reason to trigger a click event when hitting enter. You have to put your logic in the click event handler